# Can't show block on pagehide event

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile

I need to show preloader block while browser is switching between pages.
On ios event is handing and It's possible to show 'alert' but DOM manipulation seems don't work.

```
// Bind a change handler to the window location.
$(window).bind('pagehide', function(){
  alert('pagehide fired');
  $(target).show();
});
```

Comment: Where is target defined? do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: no I don't get any error, `target` is just a DOM element which defined on previous lines.

Comment: I can confirm the behavior in (mobile and not mobile) safari. In other browsers DOM manipulation in reaction to the onbeforeunload and onpagehide events are possible, but not in safari. :(